# R: Programmatically read very large data in small parts

Tags: r

I have a very large data file (`my_file.dat`) containing `31191984` rows of several variables. I would like to programmatically import this dataset into `R` in small parts e.g. data frames each of 1 million rows. At this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes), it is suggested to use `read.table()` with `nrows` option. It works for the first round of 1 million rows using this command:

```
  my_data <- read.table("path_to_my_file.dat", nrows = 1e+06)
```

How do I automate this procedure for the next rounds of 1 million rows until all parts are imported as R data frames? I am aware that one of the options could be to storing the data into `SQL` database and let `R` talk to `SQL`. However, I am looking for `R` specific solution only.

Comment: You could use the `skip` parameter along with `nrows`

Comment: See the answer I just gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52972430/2789863) for a very similar question.

Comment: What about `fread` from `data.table` also with `nrows`? Shouldn't that be faster than read.table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a CSV file, looping through the rows, using connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972229/reading-a-csv-file-looping-through-the-rows-using-connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `skip`:

```
for(i in 1:n){
read.table("file.txt",skip=i*1e+06 ,nrows=1e+06 )
}
```

As mentioned for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25932781/5224236)