# Reading huge csv table in R using connection

Tags: r

I have a .csv table with >420 millions rows, it is about 200 Go. It is way too big to open all at once.
To process it in R, I tried to import it in chunks by using a connection, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352887/strategies-for-reading-in-csv-files-in-pieces).

So, I wrote a `for-loop` (see below) with a chunk size of 1 million rows. Within the loop, I am performing some filters (removing some of the original columns, filtering out some missing values, etc). And then I am saving a `.rds` file corresponding to the iteration number. The loop ends with the error message `no lines available in input` meaning that I (theoretically) reached the last rows of the original table.

I ran the code three times to see if the results were identical. My problem is that I get each time a different number of files. And it never reaches 420.

So I am apparently not reading the whole file but only parts of it.
What am I doing wrong here?

My code here:

```
con <- file("local_path/huge_file.csv", open = "r")
chunksize <- 1000000

for(i in 1:420){
  message(paste0("Importing chunk", i, "."))
  
  if(i == 1){
    file_i <- read.csv(con, nrows = chunksize, header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
    file_i <- file_i[, c("column1", "column2")] #I am not keeping all original columns
  } else{
    file_i <- read.csv(con, nrows = chunksize,
                             header = FALSE, sep = "\t", quote = "")
    file_i <- file_i[, c(10, 12)]
    colnames(file_i) <- c("column1", "column2") #I am not keeping all original columns
  }
  
  message(paste0("Chunk", i, " loaded."))
  
  # Some controls
  if(i != 1){
    if(identical(tmp, file_i)){
      stop(paste0("Problem at i = ", i,
                  ". file_i identical with previous one."))
    }
  }
  tmp <- file_i
    if(nrow(file_i) != chunksize){
    message(paste0("Problem at i = ", i,
                   ". file_i has ", nrow(file_i), "rows."))
  }

  message(paste0("Chunk", i, " cleaned."))

  # Here I do some operations like removing NAs, converting some columns as numeric, etc
  
  # Save the chunk number i as a .rds file
  saveRDS(file_i, paste0("local_path_", i, "_20231127.rds"))
  
  message(paste0("Chunk", i, " saved."))
  
  print(i)
}
close(con)
```

Comment: Instead of a `read.csv` you should use `data.table::fread`. It is faster by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am aware of `data::fread()`, but we cannot use it with connection and 200Go is still too big.

Comment: As there is no use to read columns you are not going to keep, I would pre-process the CSV with a command line tool, such as [csvtoolkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), to subset the column data, for example: `csvcut -c column1,column2 data.csv > new.csv`

Comment: @P.Denelle if you don't use skip to skip already read rows, you will have each chunk read by be the same chunk. This made me curious why your controls looking for repeats didnt flag; maybe I dont get it

Comment: I don‘t understand why you need to work with a (explicit) file connection.

Comment: thanks for the comments all. Removing a priori some columns is a good idea. And regarding the connection, I am using it as it allows to read only some rows of the Excel file, in a consecutive fashion. The loop above does produce a different output at each iteration. 
I will orientate my search towards the `arrow` package.

Comment: How many columns does the original file have? That is, if you have 200 columns (of identical type/class) then even 2 columns are going to be hard for some laptops to read in all at once. I suggest looking into a "lazy" way to read in your data that doesn't require having it all in memory at once; examples include the `arrow` and `duckdb` packages.